# Does adding Custom Filter affect the Chain?

Tags: spring-security

If I define a filter Chain Proxy as follows:

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChai nProxy">
<security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
<security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
filters="
securityContextPersistenceFilter,
authenticationProcessingFilter" />
</security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

will the other filters in Standard Filter chain be executed? Should I define all the filters I need this way, or will they run with me explicitly putting them in the "filters"
property.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will the other filters in Standard Filter chain be executed?

No. You need all the filters you want explicitly defined.

If you insert a filter at a position using the default filter chain. Then all the filters would run 'around' yours.

The easiest way to see what filters are running is to enable the spring debug log. Search for 'debug' on the [pet clinic tutorial app page](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html) and you should see how to enable it.